# Grafana Panel Alert No Data

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, filebeat

i wondering what’s going on with my Graph panel. So basically it alert “No Data”, then a minute later, it resolved itself by alerting “OK”

I used datasource from `Elasticsearch` with `Filebeat` index

Here is my Query

[image: grafana query]

Here is my Alert Tab

[image: alert]

I just wondering why is it happening and is it normal or some misconfiguration.
Thanks